# Anonymous union with only one member

Tags: c++

I came across this piece of code, with only one member in an anonymous union (when looking at the UE4 source code to not quote it) and I was wondering about this anonymous union. 
Is it just some old code that never got cleaned up or has it something to do with alignment or anything else ?

```
struct Matrix4 {
    union { 
        __declspec(align(16)) float M[4][4];
    };

    // Methods
};
```

Comment: The alignment specifier is applied to `M` and not the union in the code you found as well? This is not a change you made when creating the example?

Comment: There are a few caveats regarding unions, and the implications of those union-isms will apply to the `M` member variables.  (I can't enumerate them off the top of my head, because I haven't used a `union` for 20+ years.)  Note that this union is an anonymous type, and is unnamed so is leveraging the "pass-through" behavior (which I think is a C11-ism), a `Matrix4 mat; mat4.M[0][0] = 0.0f;` omits the union member name since it is unnamed.  The "never got cleaned up" is my suspicion as well.

Comment: Looks to me like the author was planning on doing some stuff with MMX/SIMD register types (or similar) but never got round to it.

Comment: @StoryTeller Indeed it's applied to the member of the `union` in the original code, neither the `union` nor the `struct`

Comment: Interesting. I'm familiar with this trick when applied to the union. In compilers where the attribute may not be applied to members, this is a workaround. The member "leaks" to the enclosing scope, and the specifier applies to it via the anonymous union.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax `__declspec(align(16))` suggests that this piece of code was written for Visual Studio.

I guess that the author of such code wanted to use the peculiarity of Visual Studio's compiler not to default-initialize fields inside the `union` for performance reasons.

Please consider the example:

```
struct Matrix4 {
    alignas(16) float M[4][4];
};

// ok everywhere
static_assert( Matrix4().M[0][0] == 0 );

struct Matrix4U {
    union { 
        alignas(16) float M[4][4];
    };
};

// fails in Visual Studio
static_assert( Matrix4U().M[0][0] == 0 );
```

Here `Matrix4` does not have anonymous union inside, and its default constructor `Matrix4()` initializes `M` with zeros, as `static_assert` proves.

`Matrix4U` wrapping `M` in anonymous union (as in the question) skips zero-initialization in `Matrix4U()`, and `static_asserts` prints the error (only in MSVC):

```
<source>(15): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
<source>(15): note: failure was caused by a read of an uninitialized symbol
<source>(15): note: see usage of 'Matrix4U::M'
```

Online demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/hYcrEcnMc